error: subprocess-exited-with-error in colab how do I fix it
Having some trouble downloading the ai-economist repository in Google colab and I get the subprocess-exited-with-error come up, I have this code from below. It shows that everything is downloaded but cannot build wheels. Is there something I need to download for the subprocess error to not show?
import os, signal, sys, time
IN_COLAB = 'google.colab' in sys.modules

if IN_COLAB:
    !pip install ai-economist
    # Restart the Python runtime to automatically use the installed packages
    print("\n\nRestarting the Python runtime! Please (re-)run the cells below.")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
else:
    !pip install ai-economist

I get this error
Requirement already satisfied: ai-economist in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs==1.4.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope==0.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi==20.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astroid==2.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (2.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator==1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs==21.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall==0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4==4.9.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: black==21.5b1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (21.5b1)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach==3.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bs4==0.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi==2020.12.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (2020.12.5)
Collecting cffi==1.14.5 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached cffi-1.14.5.tar.gz (475 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click==8.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler==0.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator==5.0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (5.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml==0.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints==0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile==1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8==3.9.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (3.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: GPUtil==1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna==2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: iniconfig==1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel==5.5.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (5.5.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython==7.31.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (7.31.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils==0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.2.0)
Collecting ipywidgets==7.6.3 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached ipywidgets-7.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: isort==5.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (5.8.0)
Collecting jedi==0.18.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached jedi-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==3.0.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.8 kB)
Collecting jupyter==1.0.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (995 bytes)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client==6.1.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (6.1.12)
Collecting jupyter-console==6.4.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached jupyter_console-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (951 bytes)
Collecting jupyter-core==4.7.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (759 bytes)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (329 bytes)
Collecting jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver==1.3.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.3.1.tar.gz (53 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached lazy-object-proxy-1.6.0.tar.gz (44 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting lz4==3.1.3 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached lz4-3.1.3.tar.gz (159 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting matplotlib==3.2.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached matplotlib-3.2.1.tar.gz (40.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting matplotlib-inline==0.1.2 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached matplotlib_inline-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (380 bytes)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe==0.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune==0.8.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.8.4)
Collecting mypy-extensions==0.4.3 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.2 kB)
Collecting nbclient==0.5.3 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached nbclient-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.0 kB)
Collecting nbconvert==6.0.7 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached nbconvert-6.0.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
Collecting nbformat==5.1.3 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached nbformat-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting nest-asyncio==1.5.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached nest_asyncio-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting notebook==6.4.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached notebook-6.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.21.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached numpy-1.21.0.zip (10.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting openpyxl==3.0.7 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached openpyxl-3.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
Collecting packaging==20.9 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached packaging-20.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting pandas==1.2.4 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pandas-1.2.4.tar.gz (5.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pandocfilters==1.4.3 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pandocfilters-1.4.3.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting parso==0.8.2 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached parso-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.4 kB)
Collecting pathspec==0.8.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pathspec-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting pexpect==4.8.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare==0.7.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.7.5)
Collecting Pillow==9.0.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached Pillow-9.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting pluggy==0.13.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pluggy-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting prometheus-client==0.10.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached prometheus_client-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.18 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.18-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess==0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (0.7.0)
Collecting py==1.10.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached py-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle==2.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (2.7.0)
Collecting pycparser==2.20 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (907 bytes)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.10.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.10.1-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes==2.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from ai-economist) (2.3.1)
Collecting Pygments==2.9.0 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached Pygments-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
Collecting pylint==2.8.2 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pylint-2.8.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.3 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent==0.17.3 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.17.3.tar.gz (106 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pytest==6.2.4 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pytest-6.2.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.3 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.0 kB)
Collecting pytz==2021.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
Collecting pyyaml==5.4.1 (from ai-economist)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


Restarting the Python runtime! Please (re-)run the cells below.

What does this mean?

The issue pertains to cython version as discussed in the issues here. The solution is to use this pip install "cython<3.0.0" && pip install --no-build-isolation pyyaml==5.4.1. which works, but there is issue with python version; Suggesting version below 3.9 and since there is no effective downgrading option(to my knowledge) in collab(you can downgrade as shown here but since it requires restart we loose the installed package.

Still gives the same error, even when downgrading to 3.8

Actually this error comes up now, This error comes up, `error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`

it means the dependent pyyaml package can't be installed correctly.
try:
pip install "cython<3.0.0" && pip install --no-build-isolation pyyaml==5.4.1
it looks like the same issue as Issue importing PyYAML, cltk
refer to @apan524's comments
https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/724
